# How can I create a body text in xml android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to create title,body of text, other icons such as picture and link. How can I display the title and body of text as shown in the following picture? Which layout is better ? Constraint, Linear or Grid? How do we choose these layouts?

[image: Edit Post UI]

Answer (score 1):

**Constraint layout** is best layout & much more flexible.

For **title** & **body**, you can use **CardView** at background and place your views like TextView/Edittext, ImageView/ImageButton on it. You may need to place another Constraint Layout in cardView for its inner view

Comment: Can't I use LinearLayout for all the elements? The issue is on how to stack the two buttons at the bottom.

Comment: On what criteria do we choose layouts? What's the best layout to the above case? Do I use two cardviews for each title and body?